# How to set the interval in milliseconds so that it will consistently change once every 100ms?

Tags: java, android

I want to make my millisecond time change every 100ms, but the time I get is inconsistent sometimes the intervals I get are 99, 100 and 101. The interval I want is 100 and consistent.

as below my problem is now the resulting interval will change like number 4 and 5.

1. 19:56:16:096
2. 19:56:16.196
3. 19:56:16.296
4. 19:56:16.397
5. 19:56:16.495

while the result I want is like this below

1. 19:56:16.096
2. 19:56:16.196
3. 19:56:16.296
4. 19:56:16.396
5. 19:56:16.496

here's a screenshot of my App

[image]

here's the code I use

```
public void startTimer(){
    carousalTimer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
    carousalTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //DO YOUR THINGS

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                    Date date = new Date();
                    data = sdf3.format(time).toString();
                    aList.add(data);
                    get(data);

                }
            });

        }
    }, 100, 100); // delay
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is part of how Android works. It is a multi-threaded environment where resources are share among multiple processes.

According to the documentation Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() is the best approach for the following use cases:

> In fixed-rate execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the
> scheduled execution time of the initial execution. If an execution is
> delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background
> activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to
> "catch up." In the long run, the frequency of execution will be
> exactly the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system
> clock underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).
>
> Fixed-rate execution is appropriate for recurring activities that are
> sensitive to absolute time, such as ringing a chime every hour on the
> hour, or running scheduled maintenance every day at a particular time.
> It is also appropriate for recurring activities where the total time
> to perform a fixed number of executions is important, such as a
> countdown timer that ticks once every second for ten seconds. Finally,
> fixed-rate execution is appropriate for scheduling multiple repeating
> timer tasks that must remain synchronized with respect to one another.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long))

If it is only necessary to be visual perfect, you can set the time relative to the start time. For example by increment an index every 100ms:

```
final long DELAY = 100; // 100ms delay
AtomicInteger index = AtomicInteger(0);
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
carousalTimer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
carousalTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long time = startTime + (index.incrementAndGet() * DELAY)
                SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                Date date = new Date();
                data = sdf3.format(time).toString();
                aList.add(data);
                get(data);
            }
        });

    }
}, DELAY, DELAY);
```